# How to get Firestore rules working with service accounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As written in Firestore documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) I have a security rule like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

this rule works when I get authenticated with client library but not when I use server library as written in firebase documentation

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default Credentials. If you are using the server client libraries or the REST or RPC APIs, make sure to set up Cloud Identity and Access Management for Cloud Firestore.

How to replicate this security rule to service accounts roles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code that uses the Firebase Admin SDK with a service account to access Firestore currently can not be scoped to a particular user ID for the purpose of enforcing security rules.  All access with the Admin SDK will bypass security rules and have full control of the database.

Note that this is different than Realtime Database, which does have such a feature.

Comment: Is it just in theory or in current practice as well? My service account can't bypass my security rules, so I had to add a new security rule specifically for service account ID.

Comment: Tested: The Admin SDK doesn't work on Firestore Emulator unless the security rules all set to true: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1363#issuecomment-635834971

Comment: My service account did not bypass the rules either, until I switched API see https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore/issues/431#issuecomment-743914166