# Firestore Security Rules: How to enforce the number of fields CREATED in a Firestore document thru security rules?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am unable to restrict the number of fields in a created document using the Firestore Security Rules.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

I have 7 fields in my user document.  I would like to restrict any document CREATE attempts to the number of fields that I expect.  I have set the number to 100 which clearly is not what I am sending over to intentionally create a fail.  I would expect 100 to fail but it does not.

```
match /users/{uid} {
  // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
  allow create: if request.resource.data.size() == 100;
}
```

I have also tried the following by placing the size property directly onto the resource object with no success.

allow create: if request.resource.size() == 100;

Here is the code that attempts the CREATE operation;

```
const DEFAULT_systemRole = 'User';
  const DEFAULT_disabled = false; 
  // creates up a static sentinel value to be set on the Firestore server
  var serverTimestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(req.body.uid).set({

    // sent from client
    usernameSlug: req.body.usernameSlug,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,

    // set only here on server
    systemRole: DEFAULT_systemRole,
    disabled: DEFAULT_disabled,
    dateModified: serverTimestamp,
    dateCreated: serverTimestamp,

  }).then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully created FireStore user");
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    throw(error)
  })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to how code that writes the document.  It's not certain that your rule actually applies to the write that you're performing, since we don't know what that write really is.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this quickly in the simulator, and it seems to work for me there:

[image]

So the above security rules require 2 fields.

When I write a new document with only one field (in the screenshot), the write fails.

When I change the rules to require only one field, the same write succeeds.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I just recognized that my problem is that I am using the Firebase Admin sdk which does not support Security Rules.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by design the Firebase Admin sdk, which I happen to be using, does not support Firebase Security Rules.  Instead, the Firebase Admin sdk BYPASSES all security Rules.  So it looks like I will move all my calls to the Firebase Admin sdk and simply lock down the Firestore db with the following rule to prevent any possibility for client-side hacking.

```
  match /users/{uid} {

    allow read, write: if false;

  }
```

The following post also found the same; 
[How to get Firestore rules working with service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930891/how-to-get-firestore-rules-working-with-service-accounts#51931429)