# Is it possible to restrict firebase firestore access to only service accounts and API keys using cloud firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firebase's cloud firestore database and I would like to restrict access to this database  to two mobile apps that authenticate via API keys and one service account.

I have reviewed the [firebase documentation on implementing custom rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) but I do not see any API key or service account examples so I am unsure how to utilize rules for this use case.

From this [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930891/how-to-get-firestore-rules-working-with-service-accounts) it looks like service accounts using the firebase admin API bypass any firestore security rules, is that correct? If so is it reasonable to turn off write access entirely to any firestore collections that I only expect this service account to update?

So far I have tried something like this to allow access from the service account but it was not working as expected. I am not sure if cloud firestore rules support restricting access to only certain API keys.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sales_reps/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.email == '<first-service-account-email>';
    }
    match /gps_tracking/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.email == '<second-service-account-email>';
    }
    match /{document=\*\*} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From this stackoverflow question and answer it looks like service
> accounts using the firebase admin API bypass any firestore security
> rules, is that correct?

Yes this is correct

> If so is it reasonable to turn off write access entirely to any
> firestore collections that I only expect this service account to
> update?

Yes, since no user using a Client SDK (or the REST API) is going to update your collection(s) it is the correct aproach.

---

So concretely no need to use rules like

```
allow write: if request.auth.token.email == '<first-service-account-email>';
```

just do

```
allow write: if false;
```

for all the collections for which you only want the service account to have the write access right.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Renaud! Do you know if it is possible to restrict access to specific collections using the API key being used to access my firebase firestore? Or is that something I would need to implement with App Check?